# How to prevent snmpd from listening on port 161?

Tags: configuration, snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to force snmpd to listen on port 1610 (instead of the default port 161).

When I turn on debugging, it looks like snmpd insists on listening on port 161, in addition to any other agent address I specify.

I am running net-snmp 5.7.2 on Ubuntu.

Here is my snmpd.conf:

```
agentaddress dtlsudp:localhost:1610
agentuser root
agentgroup root
```

Here's how I launch snmpd:
`snmpd -f -r -DALL -c snmpd.conf`

I can see that snmpd parses the config file and recognizes the desired port 1610, but it tries to listen on port 161 as well!

```
read_config:parser: Found a parser.  Calling it: agentaddress / dtlsudp:localhost:1610
snmpd_ports: port spec: udp:127.0.0.1:161,udp:localhost:1610,dtlsudp:localhost:1610,udp:localhost:1610,dtlsudp:localhost:1610
netsnmp_ds_set_string: Setting APP:2 = "udp:127.0.0.1:161,udp:localhost:1610,dtlsudp:localhost:1610,udp:localhost:1610,dtlsudp:localhost:1610"
snmp_agent: final port spec: "udp:127.0.0.1:161,udp:localhost:1610,dtlsudp:localhost:1610,udp:localhost:1610,dtlsudp:localhost:1610"
```

How can I prevent snmpd from listening on port 161 ???

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `snmpd` always reads /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf unless you explicitly disable that using the `-C` option.

The following command worked.  It only read my local config file.

```
snmpd -f -DALL -C -c snmpd.conf
```